# clear input textbox value on load

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following form which is getting pre populated with values on load. I want to have empty input boxes on load using Javascript. However I do not have access to the `<body>` tag so `<body onload=""` will not work here. Is there any other way to clear the form fields on load?

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  <input name="username" id="user" value="" /><br />
  <input name="pwd" id="pass" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use window.onload instead.

```
function init() {
    // Clear forms here
    document.getElementById("user").value = "";
}
window.onload = init;
```

You could also use one of the nice wrappers for doing this in JQuery, Dojo, or you favorite Javascript library. In JQuery it would be,

```
$(document).ready(init)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
window.onload = function(){
 document.getElementById("user").value = "";
}
```

Here's an **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/EWkqs/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can run a timeout that will clear the field values. like this:

```
var t=setTimeout(function(){CLEARVALUES},3000)
```

Comment: I want something that fires onload

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a script tag just after the form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("user").value = "";</script>
```

You can also use jQuery to subscribe to both an individual element's ready (or load) event or the document.

Answer (score 0):

```
onload=()=>{
    document.getElementById('user').value='';
}
```

or

```
onload=()=>{
    document.getElementById('user').setAttribute('value','');
}
```